# Widget.Design.TabLayout twice defined error

Tags: android

i am working on a project where every thing was working fine until now where i'm getting error of values being already defined in values folder below is my styles.xml

```
</style>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title.Inverse">
        <item>?unknown_attr_ref: 1010039</item>
        <item>?unknown_attr_ref: 101034f</item>
        <item>?unknown_attr_ref: 101003f</item>
        <item>?unknown_attr_ref: 1010350</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item>@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>
        <item>@style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar.AlertDialog</item>
        <item>@bool/abc_config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item>@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>
        <item>@style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar.AlertDialog</item>
        <item>@bool/abc_config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.V11.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item>@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>
        <item>@style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar.AlertDialog</item>
        <item>@bool/abc_config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
        <item>@dimen/abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size</item>
        <item>@dimen/abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size</item>
        <item>@dimen/abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size</item>
        <item>@dimen/abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    </style>
    <style name="Platform.AppCompat">
```

it was working fine before but now it is showing duplicate values i tried changing name but i doesnt work and same is happening for dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_height">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_height">54dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_action_bar_default_height_material">56dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_action_bar_default_height_material">64dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_action_bar_default_height_material">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size">40dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size">32dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_text_size_subtitle_material_toolbar">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_text_size_subtitle_material_toolbar">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_text_size_subtitle_material_toolbar">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar">14dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_config_prefDialogWidth">320dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_config_prefDialogWidth">440dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_config_prefDialogWidth">580dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: you may be editing the debug/values. do not edit the debug files , it wont reflect. clear your project and run again

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the design library components need a style which is based on an AppCompat Theme. So try to use "Theme.AppCompat.[...]" as a parent in your style.xml.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.AppTheme">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

**Then add gradle:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

**You should update the following lines in your gradle as well:**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
targetSdkVersion 22
```

Please check your style xml code ,try this code it helps you.

Comment: Hello @geek i tried this but not working and additionaly giving me this error

Comment: Error:(23, 0) Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\KIPL-DEV2-PC\AndroidStudioProjects

Comment: i also changed my build gradle to 22.0.1

Comment: Please anyone can help me still getting error Base_Theme_AppCompat_DialogWhenLarge has already been defined in this folder (Base_Theme_AppCompat_DialogWhenLarge is equivalent to Base.Theme.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge) more... (Ctrl+F1)